# Solve for a variable in Coq

Tags: coq

Is there a way to solve for a variable in Coq? Given:

```
From Coq Require Import Reals.Reals. 

Definition f_of_x (x : R) : R := x + 1. 
Definition f_of_y (y : R) : R := y + 2.
```

I want to express

```
Definition x_of_y (y : R) : R :=
```

as something like `solve for x in f_of_x = f_of_y.` I expect to use the tactic language to then shuffle terms about. I ultimately want to end up with the correct usable definition of `y + 1.` I think want to use my definiton:

```
Compute x_of_y 2. (* This would yield 3 if R was tractable or if I was using nat *)
```

The alternative is to do it by hand with pencil/paper and then only *check* my work with Coq. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to express is the existence of a solution to the equation

```
x + 3 = x + 2
```

If so you can state it in coq as

```
Lemma solution :
  exists x, x + 3 = x + 2.
```

If it was something solvable like `x + 2 = 2 * x` then you could solve it as

```
Lemma solution :
  exists x, x + 2 = 2 * x.
Proof.
  exists 2. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But then of course there are no solutions to `x + 3 = x + 2`.
If you want instead a solution, with `y` fixed to

```
x + 3 = y + 2
```

you have to quantify over `y`:

```
Lemma solution :
  forall y, exists x, x + 1 = y + 2.
Proof.
  intro y.
  eexists. (* Here I'm saying I want to prove the equality and fill in the x later *)
  eapply plus_S_inj.
  rewrite plus_0.
  reflexivity.
Defined.

Print solution. (* You will see the y + 1 here *)
```

Here I assume some lemmata that help me manipulate numbers:

```
Lemma plus_S_inj :
  forall x y z t,
    x + z = y + t ->
    x + (S z) = y + (S t).
Admitted.

Lemma plus_0 :
  forall x,
    x + 0 = x.
Admitted.
```

You probably have similar lemmata for your notion of `R` (I don't know which it is so I cannot go any further.)

Comment: Thank you I had not understood existential quantification's use yet!!

But could you finish the final `Lemma` in your answer if `x` & `y` are `R`? I do `intros y.` but then have to make the leap to use `exists (y + 1).` I don't know how to do the algbraeic manipulation of subtracting 1 from both sides so the x is alone...

Comment: I updated my answer, but then I believe manipulations of terms of type `R` should be left for separate questions.

Comment: yes I agree with you. I also updated my question to show I'm importing Reals.Reals from Coq Standard Library to get `R`.

Comment: It's unclear to me how I would use `solution` as you have done it. In your case, where we're dealing with `nat`, I would think `solution` would be usable like `Compute solution 2. (* yields 3 *)`. Instead `Check solution 2.` yields `exists x, x + 1 = 2 + 2` which is a `Prop`. Can I do anything with this result?

Comment: I already touch on this in my answer. If you print it, you can see that it is the constructor `existT`, you can match on it to get the witness out. If I answered your question, please consider marking it as solved.